# What is the time zone of the events featured by the SEC?

Tags: sec, edgar

The [SEC Edgar Filing Tracker](https://sec.report/) is the official place to track official company filings. Let us take the example of [Apple reports](https://sec.report/CIK/0000320193). You see a long list of filings and a Date with a rather exact hour of report upload (e.g. `2021-02-08 16:31:03`). What is the time zone of this date stamp?

Comment: "The [SEC Edgar Filing Tracker](https://sec.report) is the official place to track official company filings" — No. That is a third-party website. Here is the official website: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time zone used by SEC filings is [Eastern Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone). Specifically, Eastern Standard Time (UTC-05:00) or Eastern Daylight Saving Time (UTC-04:00), whichever was in effect at the time of filing.

Reference: [17 CFR § 232.13 - Date of filing; adjustment of filing date](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/232.13)